# Rendering Unicode Combining Overstruck Characters in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, diacritics

### First, some background...

Unicode combining diacritical marks are weird.

For a web application I am working on I need to make use of all of the [Unicode Combining Diacritical Marks](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf). I was able to figure out pretty quickly how to create combined characters programmatically in JavaScript such that they display to the console as expected. For example, to combine the placeholder character `◌` with the combining grave accent use `\u3000\u25cc`:

[image: placeholder character with the combining grave accent]

I can output this in the HTML and it looks good in the Elements view of the Dev Tools:

[image: placeholder character with the combining grave accent, shown in HTML (dev tools)]

However, the rendered result in the web page is not right:

[image: placeholder character with the combining grave accent, shown in HTML (web page)]

I can fix this by inverting the order of the character and mark to `\u25cc\u3000`. Then things look weird in the dev tools:

[image: placeholder character with the combining grave accent, inverted]

But the resulting web page looks correct.

[image: placeholder character with the combining grave accent, shown correctly in HTML]

This approach (inverting the order) has worked for most of the combining diacritical marks.

### Now to the problem

There are a subset of combining diacritical marks that are meant to be overlays on top of the character. You can see them in action in the above-referenced PDF specification from Unicode:

[image: overstruck diacritics, displayed]

[image: overstruck diacritics, descriptions]

When I try to render them in HTML, the marks never overlay. Here is an example of the problem in action:

https://codepen.io/joeskeen/pen/OJBKPXK

I can produce them in the console of the dev tools just fine, just like any other combining diacritical marks:

[image: long solidus overlay in dev tools console]

If I try with the combining mark before (`\u0338\u25cc`), this is what comes out:

[image: long solidus overlay before modified character]

If I try with the combining mark after (`\u25cc\u0338`), this is what comes out:

[image: long solidus overlay after modified character]

I don't think I'm misunderstanding how it should display, as this is the result I expect from the Unicode reference PDF:

[image]

Are there any weird tricks (short of putting them in separate spans and using CSS to move them on top of one another) that can be employed to get this to work?

Comment: One side note on browsers: I tried this on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on Windows, and Chrome, Edge, and Safari on Mac OS X. In all cases except Safari I get the wrong result. So I wonder if this is a combination of browser and font compatibility with those Unicode characters.

Comment: That's just how your font renders them. Use a font that's able to render them correctly. For instance it seems your default monospace font (at least the one used in your console) does https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/OJBKNLX

Comment: I guess if I want a consistent experience across devices, I can't leave it to the default font to render, I'm going to need to embed a web font.

Comment: Combining diacritical marks (i.e. in the range 0300–036F) should _follow_ the base character, not precede it. From section 2.11 of the [Unicode Standard v 15.0](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch02.pdf) with my emphasis added: _"In the Unicode Standard, **all combining characters are to be used in sequence following the base characters to which they apply**"_. So your examples with the combining character preceding the base character may be _valid_ Unicode sequences, but they are not _meaningful_ Unicode sequences, and how Dev Tools or browsers (mis)handle them is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, regarding issues with rendering, see this question in [the Unicode FAQs](https://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html): _"When I use a combining sequence, why does it not display correctly?"_. Part of their answer (but read the whole thing!) is: _"Your problem is most likely a limitation of the layout engine and/or font you are using..."_, so as an initial step identify and use a font that definitely supports the characters want to render, as @Kaiido has already mentioned.

Comment: Finally, I think your question needs to be a bit more specific. Can you provide code (HTML, JavaScript or whatever) that is not doing what you want in a specific environment. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for clarification. Be sure to specify the target environment, the O/S and the font you are using. I think your question is fairly broad as it stands, and needs a bit more focus. (I fully understand that _ultimately_ you want something that works in any browser on any O/S.)